# Has an SRB been considered for use in orbit to launch to escape velocity?

Tags: deep-space, srb

Has an SRB been considered for use in orbit to launch to escape velocity to deep space? Consider SRB disposable and deep space vehicle continues on liquid propulsion. SRB conserves liquid propellants for later orbit maneuvers for deep space vehicle.

Comment: I like your question! You could ask a follow-up question more focused on the reasons and trade-offs between solid and liquid in these cases as well.

Answer (score 16):

This is referred to as 'kick stage' motor and is commonly used. One example being [Star 37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_37). A larger [Star 48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_48) is what sent New Horizons on the way to Pluto

Comment: Star 48 was the motor in the PAM-D stage, referred to in my answer, as well.

Comment: I have seen "kick motor" more often then "kick stage". But both are correct, I guess.

Comment: @Polygnome Funnily enough, even [ATK STAR product page](https://www.orbitalatk.com/defense-systems/missile-products/STAR/default.aspx) refers to them as Motors/Stages

Comment: oh man!  I did my Propulsion teacher a disservice for not suggesting the "motor" keyword.  Industry jargon is that solid rockets are motors and liquid are engines.  Good answer.

Answer (score 8):

There's at least one example, the Inertial Upper Stage (nee Interim Upper Stage) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_Upper_Stage

Wikipedia's summary is:

> The Inertial Upper Stage (IUS), originally designated the Interim Upper Stage, was a two-stage solid-fueled rocket upper stage developed by Boeing for the United States Air Force beginning in 1976 for raising payloads from low Earth orbit to higher orbits or interplanetary trajectories following launch aboard a Titan 34D or Titan IV rocket, or from the payload bay of the Space Shuttle.

A pertinent search phrase would be "solid upper stages."

Answer (score 7):

The [PAM-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_Assist_Module) was another solid fuel upper stage used on the Space Shuttle and Delta II launchers.

[image]

For the Shuttle application, one or more PAMs were carried in cradles in the payload bay.  They were spring launched out of the bay, as in this picture, and the SRM ignited at a safe distance.

Comment: Can you clarify "...solid fuel upper stage used on the Space Shuttle..."? Did the space shuttle cary a satellite into orbit and the satellite included a PAM-D? Sounds scary!

Comment: Sure, added a few words and a picture. The shuttle carried IUSes too - now that was a giant SRM. http://www.americaspace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/tdrse.jpg  At least the PAMs went straight up - the IUSes came soaring just over the crew cabin.

Comment: Centaur (the specialized Centaur-G) was planned to be flown out of the Shuttle payload bay as well, but post-Challenger they decided having another Hydrolox stage in there was too scary and shelved it.

Comment: Yeah, I worked on the sim for the Centaur G Prime. Trying to dump all that prop when the shuttle did an ascent abort was ... interesting. http://arstechnica.com/science/2015/10/dispatches-from-the-death-star-the-rise-and-fall-of-nasas-shuttle-centaur/